# How to set up Unikey the same way as VPSKeys in Windows

Tags: keyboard-layout, internationalization

I am trying to switch a laptop to Ubuntu for a family member. Currently the laptop runs Windows and a program called VPSKeys, which is used to add Vietnamese accents and other characters when using a US Keyboard. I have found Unikey on GNU/Linux could be a replacement for it, but the documentation is written in vietnamese, and since I do not understand how VPSKeys work, or read vietnamese, I can't think of a way to replicate the same functionality.

My question is: Has anyone used Unikey. Does it behave the same way as VPSKeys on Windows? Are there tweaks required to get it to behave the same way?

The Unikey site is located at: https://code.google.com/p/ibus-unikey/

More info on VPS Keys: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPSKeys

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

ibus-unikey is packaged for Ubuntu and available in the Ubuntu archive, so the first thing I would like to say is: Install it from the Ubuntu archive instead of downloading it from e.g. Google directly.

Actually, if you install the Vietnamese language in Ubuntu, ibus-unikey gets automatically installed.

I have absolutely no idea if there are differences compared to VPSKeys. But judging from the [positive user feedback from some users of Ubuntu 12.04](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/ibus-unikey/), it's probably easy to handle.